# How can I display Flutter Firebase sum of firestore document values?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I display Flutter Firebase sum of firestore document values on the screen.
This is how I get the sum with forEach.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpaHb.png)

`print("subTotal1 $subTotal1");` This is how I print it to the console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K12sG.png)

How can I show this sum from the console on the screen?

Thanks for your help

How can I display Flutter Firebase sum of firestore document values on the screen.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FutureBuilder widget to show this on screen.

First Create a function to return a double or int value.

```html
  Future<double> getSubTotal() async {
    double total = 0;
    await db.collection('users').get().then((value) {
      for (var doc in value.docs) {
        List<dynamic> listGenGid = doc.data()['GenGid'] ?? [];
        for (var item in listGenGid) {
          total += num.parse(item['amount1']);
        }
      }
    });
    return total;
  }
```

and then use it in the widget tree.

```html
  FutureBuilder<double>(
    future: getSubTotal(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text('Subtotal: ${snapshot.data!.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Text('Loading...');
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      } else {
        return const Text('Total: 0.00');
      }
    },
  ),
```

It will look like this.

```html
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExampleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleScreen> createState() => _ExampleScreenState();
}

class _ExampleScreenState extends State<ExampleScreen> {
  Future<double> getSubTotal() async {
    double total = 0;
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then((value) {
      for (var doc in value.docs) {
        List<dynamic> listGenGid = doc.data()['GenGid'] ?? [];
        for (var item in listGenGid) {
          total += num.parse(item['amount1']);
        }
      }
    });
    return total;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<double>(
        future: getSubTotal(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text('Subtotal: ${snapshot.data!.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text('Loading...');
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            return const Text('Total: 0.00');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is how it'll looks like]

Comment: Thank you for your suggested solution.
When I ran the codes, I encountered the problem below

No MeiaQuery widget ancestor found……..

Comment: if you are using the example widget. you must consider it as a new route ```Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ExampleScreen(),
                  ),
                );``
`
 just to see the working view of it.

Otherwise, use the first two snippets in your own widget tree. 

let me know, how are you using the above code?

Comment: I used the codes at the bottom that you sent as a picture.

Comment: DholaSain Thank you very much, the codes worked successfully.

Comment: You are welcome. Mark the answer as solution/correct answer.